# Open graph doesn't publish on the wall feed

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

I've made an app with open graph.
Once I publish an action, it doesn't publish on my wall. 
It publishes on  the **activity feed** instead.

Here is my code for publishing

```
function postCook()
{
  FB.api(
    '/me/[my app namespace]:cook?'
    ,
    'post',
    { recipe: 'http://www.xxx.com/Sample.html'
        ,access_token : 'MY TOKEN'},
    function(response) {
       if (!response || response.error) {
          alert( response.error.message );
       } else {
          alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
       }
    });
}
```

I also tried to follow the instruction here [Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publish-action/#create)
According to this tutorial, I've seen that Open Graph can publish to News Feed.
But I cannot make my app publish to News Feed.

Do I have to set any parameters to force it to publish on News feed (on my wall)?

Which permission I have to request?

publish_actions or publish_stream?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot force Open Graph actions to be published to the news feed. Facebook keep tight control over the feed and by default, your OG actions always get published to the activity feed. And sometime only do they reach the News Feed (of your friends - never seen mine in my own feed).

So that's it, you cannot force it. Although, don't worry too much about this, OG actions actually get published often enough to allow "virality" of your app, and good reach of new user. It's definitly better than a `share` action, even if this one get published to the News Feed instantly.

Comment: Thanks @Simon for your explanation.
That means eventhough OG actions get published to my activity feed, sometimes a friend of mine can see it on his news feed?

Comment: Also, I've checked facebook developer page and it mentions that **/me/feed** feature will be removed soon. This means, from now on, I should use OG as a main api for my app?

Comment: Absolutely! The problem with `publish_stream` (allowing posting to `me/feed/`) is that it will open a second login screen where user are able to enable/disable the feature right on. This result in higher bounce rate and less visibility in the end - OG actions can also be disabled, but only one by one through your account settings, which happen less often.

Comment: Ah! I've never thought about that before. 
Good point. ^_^

Comment: I have one more quick question.
Is this **http://i.imgur.com/p64XU.png** published by OG?